# Get the sum of rows in dompdf

Tags: php, mysqli, dompdf

I have attendance table like the following.
[image]

```
ID      date_in     time_in     time_out
 1     2017-05-04   8.10        16.20
 1     2017-05-05   6.10        12.20
 5     2017-05-04   9.30        16.22
 5     2017-05-05   8.20        16.23
 ....
```

I want to get the ot hours per employee for searched month and print the report and i'm using dompdf for reports.My desired output report is :

```
 ID     Name     Total OTHours
 1      John      14.20
 5      Smith     22.20
```

I worked with the following code. But the sum of ot hours not working and the pdf file is not working. Please can someone assist me to find the solution???

```
 $query = "
    SELECT * FROM employee_personal_details e
    INNER JOIN attendance_details a ON e.emp_id = a.emp_id
    WHERE MONTH(a.date_in) = '$monthSearch' 
    GROUP BY e.emp_id ";

     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

       $output = "
            <table>
                <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Total OT Hours</th>
                </tr>
               ";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

 $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td>'.$row["emp_id"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["emp_fullName"].'</td>';


  //calculate the time difference 
  $datetime1 = new DateTime($row['time_out']);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($row['time_in']);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  $workedHours = $interval->format('%h'.'.'.'%I');

    //expected hours 
    $expectedHour=8;

    //calculate the ot hours    
    $ot = $workedHours-$expectedHour;

    if($ot>0.3){
       $sumot += $ot;
    }


$output .= '
   <td>'.$sumot.'</td>     
  </tr>
 ';
}

  $output .= '</table>';

 //echo $output;
 $dompdf->loadHtml($output);
```

Comment: What data type are `time_in` and `time_out`?

Comment: Sir I used varchar data type.

Comment: yikes, that's going to make it difficult. Why not use a `DATETIME` for both? Or even just `TIME`?

Comment: SIr, I used the that code in another part and it works fine. I can not get the sum of $ot in while loop for each employee.

Comment: how you get 22.20 for smith can you explain ? @lak

Comment: SIr, i give a sample only. I attached an attendance image in my question. I want to get the sum of ot hours which are more than 0.3 (30 minutes) in dompdf file. I can not get the sum in while loop.